# BackboneJS - Magnific popup not firing youtube video

Tags: backbone.js, youtube, handlebars.js, magnific-popup

I want to show youtube videos in the Magnific popup http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/. The URl for the youtube video I get from a JSON file which I insert in my HTML with `HandlebarsJS`. So far so good, when I check the `<a href>` with the webinspector, the correct link is available.

Somehow though, when I click on it, the Magnific popup opens, but the youtube video is not firing, instead I get an error message. It seems like as soon the popup opens, or rather, when Magnific popup gets triggered, it completely disattaches itself from my `BackboneJS` App. Can this be true?

In my HTML (video.html) I have:

```
<a class="vidPopup" href="youtubelink here">
```

and in the Backbone View i created event:

```
    template: 'video', //referring to the video.html
    events: {
        'click .vidPopup': 'seeVid'
    },

    seeVid: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.vidPopup').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,
            fixedContentPos: false
        });
    }
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: seeVid is called after render ? + better use this.$el.find('.vidPopup') instead $('.vidPopup')

Comment: This didnt solve it :-/

Comment: do you call seeVid after view render() ?

Comment: hmm, dont really get your question - seeVid is a click event :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself! Since the Youtube API returns the ID of the youtube video I just had to do this:

```
<a class="vidPopup" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}}">
```

I didnt have to change the popup settings

Comment: Didn't you have to use the `embed` version of that `watch` url?